# SSAS - Data Source: Maximum Number of Connections not working

Tags: sql-server, database, ssas, olap

I was playing with the Option "Maximum Number of Connections" within a Microsoft SSAS Multidimensional OLAP Solution. According to following article, SSAS will open more Connection to the Database and will process several Partitions.

http://henkvandervalk.com/how-to-process-a-ssas-molap-cube-as-fast-as-possible-part-2

When I change the value (16, 20 etc.) and monitor the connection in the activity monitor, I always see that SSAS only open 10 Connection at the same time. Is this option in a relation with other options ? When I change it to 4, then only 4 partitions will be process in parallel.

Thanks for any advice and hints.

My SSAS Options:
 - ThreadPool \ Process \ MaxThreads: 320
 - ThreadPool \ Query \ MaxThreads: 64

My Server:
 - 32 Cores
 - 512 GB RAM

Answer (score 1):

look at the data source connection to the underlying database.  The default number of connections there is 10.

Comment: I have following setting:
Connections: Maximum number of concurrent connection: 0